# Folland, Real Analysis, Theorem 1.14

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am confused about the proof of Theorem 1.14 from Folland's *Real Analysis*, in particular, the highlighted parts in the attached image:

1. Why is the yellow part true?
2. How is the green part useful in the proof?

[image: see image here]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Look at how $\mu(E)$ is calculated (in (1.12)), it's an infimum over certain covers of $E$. If that infimum is finite, we must be able to find covers whose corresponding series get arbitrarily close to that infimum (from above). This follows essentially directly from the definition of an infimum.
2. This is not supposed to be 'useful', it's just the $\sigma$-finiteness of $\mu_0$, which we are assuming to prove the last result. If you're asking how it's used in the proof, since each set $A_j$ has finite measure with respect to $\mu$, then so does each set $E \cap A_j$ and the previous result establishes equality of $\mu$ and $\nu$ in that case.

Comment: Thank you very much! May I further ask about 1.? I wonder whether it means the proof can be:

We can choose $\\{A_j\\}_1^{\infty}$ with $A_j$'s being disjoint s.t. 

$$\mu(A)=\sum_1^{\infty} \mu(A_j) = \sum_1^{\infty} \mu_0(A_j) < \mu^*(E) + \epsilon = \mu(E) + \epsilon $$
for any $\epsilon$.

I'm confused about how the assumption "$\mu(E)<\infty$" is used in the proof. Thanks!

Comment: @sam2018 When $\mu(E) = \infty$, for any cover in (1.12) the corresponding series diverges, so you don't get an inequality $\mu(A) < \mu(E) + \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon$, you only get $\mu(A) = \mu(E) = \infty$. In the proof this means that you're not guaranteed to have $\mu(A \setminus E) < \epsilon$ for some finite $\epsilon > 0$, so all you get in the next line is $\mu(E) \leq \nu(E) + \mu(A \setminus E)$, which is not enough to conclude $\mu(E) \leq \nu(E)$.